# Intraday time window backtesting Pine script

Tags: testing, time, pine-script, back-testing

How can you backtest your strategy only within a specific time window on an intraday basis?

I'm testing a combination of MACD and BB on a timeframe of 1 minute. But I only want to enter a long or short position at UTC+2 between 10am and 1430 and 1600 and 2000 for CME listed futures.
I want to exit any open position within X minutes outside of the entry window.

In a simplified way, my code currently looks like below:

```
longentry = crossover(macd, signal) and src <= lowerBB
shortentry = crossunder(macd, signal) and src >= upperBB

longclose = crossunder(src, lowerBB)
shortclose = crossover(src, upperBB)

if longentry
    strategy.entry("id=LONG", strategy.long)
    
if shortentry
    strategy.entry("id=SHORT", strategy.short)
```

Your assistance would be much appreciated.

Thanks and best regards,

Bas

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example script of how to set up a time window for your trades. Below you will see a couple inputs. One is a bool to turn our filter on and off and the other is the time we would like to trade between. We then create a condition that checks if we are outside of our time, and that we have filter trades checked off. Then we add that to our entry with "and not timeFilter". I added some background color so you can see where exemption lies.

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)
    
useTimeFilter = input(false, "Use Time Session Filter", input.bool,    group="Filters")  
timeSession   = input("0000-0300", "Time Session To Trade In", input.session, group="Filters")    

timeFilter = na(time(timeframe.period, timeSession + ":1234567", "GMT-2")) == true and useTimeFilter 

longentry = crossover(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))

shortentry = crossunder(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))

longclose = crossunder(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28)) 

shortclose = crossover(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))

if longentry and not timeFilter
    strategy.entry("LONG", strategy.long)

if longclose and not timeFilter
    strategy.entry("SHORT", strategy.short)

strategy.close("LONG", when=longclose, comment="Long Close")

strategy.close("SHORT", when=shortclose, comment="Short Close")

bgcolor(timeFilter ? color.red : na)
```

All the best,

Bjorgum

Comment: Hi Bjorgum, thanks for your quick reply! From your above I have some questions. 1) when backtesting I still see that entries are being made in the no trade time, is your suggested added code trying to avoid any trades in the no trade time? 2) is there a reason you have not added a "if shortentry and not tieFilter" 3) how would you suggest I can add session breaks? The idea is that I don't want to trade the first period on an opening and just before the close of the session. Both for US and European session on US exhange traded futures. Happy to hear your thoughts! Regards Bas

Comment: Ive edited the answer to include a complete script with substituted values. at this link https://www.tradingview.com/x/dizffd4o/ you can see the background turns red and no trades outside of the specified time. If you would like to create a second window then duplicating some code would be required. Have a look and let me know if the window isn't working

Comment: Thank you very much Bjorgum and much appreciated! It is working now! All the best. Rgds Bas